# Question on Axler 3.B.11

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Problem 3.B.11 in Axler's book states:

> Suppose $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ are injective linear maps such that $S_1 S_2 \cdots S_n$ makes sense. Prove that $S_1 S_2 \cdots S_n$ is injective.

My main question is: does this problem just boil down to this product being injective as a map of sets? I can prove that the composition of two injective maps is injective, and by induction, that the product of $n$ injective maps is injective. I feel that there must be more to it where I somehow use the fact that the $S_i$ are linear. Perhaps Axler intended for me to prove that the kernel of the product is trivial. With that said, is there anything that makes a purely set-theoretic proof "wrong" in the context of linear maps?

Comment: No. nothing more to it. Linearity is not needed.

Comment: Also that should hold for everything that has a "forgetful functor" (dont worry if you dont know this, it just means that you can consider something as a set and forget the structure). However, epics can get weird. But for finite dimensional vector spaces, respectively vector spaces without topological structure you are golden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the purely set theoretical proof that composites of injective functions are injective. It also applies to linear maps. Arguably, for linear maps the proof becomes conceptually a tiny bit easier though, since you only have to consider a single element, which is send to zero, as opposed to two elements, which coincide after applying the functions...